# Are there any constructed languages designed with a constructed script, both aiming to be international and auxiliary?

Tags: writing-systems

[Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) is a beautiful constructed script, used to write the natural languages of Korean, Jeju, Hokkien, and Cia-Cia, perhaps others.  The shape of the letters mimic the shape of the mouth, and a letter for a voiceless consonant is directly related to the letter for its voiced counterpart.  Personally, I think it's brilliant and should be adopted worldwide, perhaps with some additions to consider sounds that do not exist in Korean (by far the most dominant language using it).

One idea of constructed international auxiliary languages is that those languages should have a simple and logical grammar to be easy to learn.  But it appears most of those languages are still written with the Latin alphabet, which doesn't have much or any connection between the look of a letter and its pronunciation — this still needs to be learned by heart.  A learner cannot derive the pronunciation of a previously unknown letter from its shape.

Have there been any designs of constructed languages, aiming to be international auxiliary languages (thus not counting fictional alien/fantasy languages), which from the start had a dedicated constructed script designed to be as simple as possible, yet universally applicable?

Comment: Well arguably the simplest script is the one you already know, and a majority of people are familiar with the Latin script...

Comment: @curiousdannii Pragmatically true; also pragmatically, the same argument is used to describe why English is currently the main international language — constructed languages are often coming from idealistic principles moreso than pragmatism, and some idealist out there might have thought radically and rethought not only the language but also the script.

Answer (score 1):

I found one language called [Bliss Symbolics](http://www.blissymbolics.org/) that is

1. It is an [International Auxiliary Language](http://interlanguages.net/)
2. It has its [own character set](http://www.blissymbolics.org/images/Bliss_English_SPSM_10964.pdf), not based on Latin characters or any other character set.

I also found another IAL that doesn't use latin characters called [Temenia](https://www.temenia.org/Temenia/index.html) that uses Greek characters instead of Latin.  While this language doesn't apply exactly to your question, you seem to be interested in NON-Latin based character IAL's.